# ODAC and Unicode

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I have problem with ODAC 6.2. In page about ODAC written that ODAC support Unicode. Now I use TOraSQl component and I connect  to Unicode table in Oracle. I can not view Unicode data in table. I see only ANCII code. 
pls, help me. I think TOraSql doesn't support Unicode ;)

Comment: You need Version 2009 for unicode support. Maybe that'sthe problem.

Comment: @Gamecat: Only for viewing data in components connected to TDataSource, but not for getting data from the server into WideString fields.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I only use DevArt [Sql Server Data Access Components](http://www.devart.com/sdac/), but I guess they are similar enough to the [Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.devart.com/odac/) that it doesn't matter for the purpose of answering your question.

For string fields of the database a `TWideStringField` component will be created, and its `Value` property returns a WideString. Something like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  w: WideString;
begin
  for i := 0 to MSQuery1.FieldCount - 1 do begin
    if MSQuery1.Fields[i] is TWideStringField then
      w := TWideStringField(MSQuery1.Fields[i]).Value;
  end;
end;
```

So the components most definitely support Unicode, but you can't simply connect a table, a data source component and a grid in Delphi versions prior to Delphi 2009 and expect this to show you Unicode text - the VCL in those Delphi versions isn't able to display Unicode strings. You could use the [TNT Unicode Controls](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/tntunicodecontrols/index), although I can't say whether there are data aware controls (I have no experience with TNT controls).

Alternatively the [Virtual Treeview](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=33) by Mike Lischke works in earlier Delphi versions and is using the Unicode API calls.

But it would be much better to simply use Delphi 2009 with its Unicode-capable VCL.

Comment: Would you recommend SDAC over ADO in Win32? If so, why?

Comment: I have no experience with ADO, so I can't compare them; however SDAC has served us very well for our projects, and with UniDAC the case has only become stronger - transparent access to several SQL servers while using a very thin layer over the native access library, sensible pricing and good support. Maybe there is no need to switch to SDAC from ADO, but back then when I researched our options for MS SQL Server access from Delphi 5 Professional, SDAC seemed the best option all around, and it has indeed worked well.